# upload dnn application on system's dnn environment

Tags: file-upload, dotnetnuke

I have installed a dotnetnuke environment on my system and i am logged in from admin. I have already created a dotnetnuke web application and I want to upload this dotnetnuke web application on my system's dotnetnuke environment. So what is the procedure to upload my dotnetnuke web application on system's dotnetnuke environment. kindly help me waiting for reply.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways.

1) The most common, and likely one that will work the best is to backup the files and the database for your local DNN install. Restore those to your production environment.

2) May work, requires that all the custom modules are also installed in production. Go to host/sites and you can Export the portal. Copy the files that get created from this export, located in /portals/_default/ to your production /portals/_default/ folder. Then go to the Admin/ Site Wizard page and apply that template to your existing site.

## 1 would be my recommended option.